# My background image doesn't expand fully or show up for the full size. Trouble with background image in html section

Tags: python, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on Bootstrap and I'm pretty new to front-end. I don't have a CSS file, all i have is a html file included in my python django project. In this file I', trying to put a background image from my section.

This image doesn't show up fully or expand to the full size. I'm not sure how to make it responsive background section with the image included and I'm not sure how to make sure this section atleast expands to full size or a size of page. Can you please help.

Whatever i try to find online shows as CSS, and i don't want to include css right now. Just want to keep it simple with boostrap html file. Here is the code below.

```
<section class="jumbotron text-center" style="background:transparent url({%static 'workspace.jpg'%}) no-repeat center center /cover">
    <div class="container">`enter code here`
            <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Name heading</h1>
            <p class="lead font-weight-bold text-muted">Test 2</p>
            <p>
            <a href="mailto:test@gmail.com" class="btn btn-info my-2">Email</a>
            </p>
      </div>
</section>
```

Comment: background-size:cover; and background-position:center; background-repeat:no-repeat;

Comment: Can you please let me know how to include this in the above code.

Comment: you can add this code style tag like this <style>.jumbotron .text-center{background-size:cover; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;}</style> i would suggest you to add a specific call to your section the style will only effect the specific div only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a background image to a container with inline CSS you can do this:

Note*: Make sure to remove the `border: 1px solid red;`. This was just for demonstration.

```html
<div class="container" style="border: 1px solid red; background-image: url('https://i0.wp.com/wptavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/stack-overflow.png?ssl=1'); background-size: 100% 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
  
     <p style="padding: 100px;">content</p>

</div>
```

Comment: @zack no worries mate glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

you can add this code in the style tag like this `<style>.jumbotron .text-center{background-size:cover; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;}</style>`i would suggest you to add a specific call to your section the style will only effect the specific div only.

if you want add inline the do like this `style="background-image:url(img);background-size:cover; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center; "`